# How to buld with MAKE and only --silent output on screen, but get full output to log file

Tags: bash, make

How can I redirect output from MAKE i such a way that I get only --silent output to screen, but full MAKE-output to a log file?

Or can this be achieved through some sdout/stderr redirection magic?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question fully. Doesn't 'make > log' work well enough?

Comment: I do not think that's a good question... if you want **full** output to the file, then use `make > file.log 2>&1` and you'ill get a "--silent" output to screen. This is a very basic shell usage.

Comment: @D4RIO - worth being an answer, not a comment:-)

Answer (score 5):

```
make > log-file 2>&1
```

or

```
make 2>&1 | tee log-file | filter
```

Where filter is a program that passes only what you want to see. Use grep or sed or something else.

Comment: to @David Oneill On linux you can also do `make | tee /dev/stderr | filter > filtered-log` this does the opposite. But /dev/stderr, /dev/stdout, /dev/stdin, /dev/fd/* is not available on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered before with a comment:

> if you want full output to the file,
>   then use make > file.log 2>&1 and
>   you'ill get a "--silent" output to
>   screen. This is a very basic shell
>   usage.

and 4 days have passed, i think that it no longer need to be responded.

Comment: That's not what the question requested, though. `make --silent` doesn't print the commands as they are executed (as if they were all prefixed by `@`), but you still get their output.

Comment: 1st: The other answer was just a copy of the command

2nd: I was very clear in saying "_if you want **full** output to the file_", requesting edition for _and you'ill get a "--silent" output to screen_ would be better since my comment has 2 'great comment' votes and a request to put it as answer. What we want are answers, so try to help.

Comment: It seemed a bit harsh to vote this down. It was already a comment, before I added my answer. My answer just is an incremental improvement. It does not deserve a negative score, so I bumped it back up to 0.